# The correct way to commit an operation in multi-user apps

Tags: design-patterns, transactions, logic

Suppose we have simple sign up app, where nicks should be unique.
And two people decide to sign up at the same time.

First I have to check if the nick already exists.
If it does, then add new user to the DB if it doesn't,
Something like this:

```c++
if (!db.userExists("John")) {
  ..some operations..
  db.save(new User("John"));
}
else
  print("already exists");
```

At first glance everything looks simple.

But what will happen, if both people choose the nick "John" and run the script at the same time?

The person will commit the operation during a gap between `if` and `save` instructions at another person's side. As result, it will overlap the other user.

So the question is **how do you account for operations like this one?**
Maybe it's too paranoid :))

Comment: Depends on the framework you are using.. Frameworks such as Spring, Dropwizard etc provide annotations to make something transactional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mechanism that facilitates this kind of operations, Depending on the programming language and platforms, different implementations. But generally two users doing the same thing at exactly the same time in micro mil sec is a rare thing, and if it happens only one will win the race, be it by database table lock, network, timestamps, computer speed and million other reasons.

If you have done all the usual procedures of as required, you should be good, in fact if the table is well created with unique username, then the database wont allow two same values to be set at the same time, table locks.

This is my 50 cents.

Regards.